# how to change text value within an element?

Tags: jquery, replace

How do you change the text for all within the `a` to

> continue reading

using jquery

```
<div class="post-read">
<a href="http://www.google.com">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Do it with jQuery inside of a document ready handler (`$(fn)`)...

```
$('.post-read a').text('continue reading');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/svMCv/).

For the sake of it, here is how to do it without jQuery....

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName('post-read')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
    textProperty;

if (anchor.textContent) {
    textProperty = 'textContent';
} else if (anchor.innerText) {
    textProperty = 'innerText';
}
anchor[textProperty] = 'continue reading';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/pXAcX/).

This will work good for your piece of HTML, but it isn't too generic.

If you don't care about setting `innerText` property, you could use...

```
anchor.textContent = anchor.innerText = 'continue reading';
```

I wouldn't recommend it though.

Comment: Is that a typo or can we really use more than one equality sign while assigning (refer to the last code block in your answer :))?

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
$('.post-read a').html('continue reading');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.post-read a').html("continue reading")
```

Answer (score 3):

Through the text property in jQuery that changes the inner text of the `<tag>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.postread a').text("your new text here ");
}
```

Comment: you will only need the
 $(document).ready(function ()
{
}
because you can't select any of the html tags before the whole document is loaded

Comment: jQuery has no `innerText()` method.