# How to change text of anchor tag on click using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change text of anchor tag on click event using jquery.

Anchor tag :

```
 <a id="view_email" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> View Email</a>
```

JQuery Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view_email").click(function(){
        $(this).text() = "abc@gmail.com";
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this).text() = "abc@gmail.com";` is wrong

Comment: So add a class....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change text value within an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961416/how-to-change-text-value-within-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view_email").click(function(){
        $(this).text("abc@gmail.com");//you will loose <i> tag
        //$(this).html("<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> View Email")//better to use html instead of text.
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="view_email" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> View Email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

.text() is a method and you cant assign to this method call;

try

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view_email").click(function(){
        $(this).textContent = "abc@gmail.com";
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

since the text() function will also replace the envelope icon with text , render the text using html() along with the icon as shown below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#view_email").click(function(){
        $(this).html("<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>abc@gmail.com");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="view_email" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> View Email</a>
```